# Condense this UPDATE statement with all these IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

So I am writing an update script to change a column in a couple of spots and I am trying to find a MUCH better way to condense this code down than having a bunch of "IF NOT EXISTS" statements.

This is the current code in question and I am not sure if CASE Statements would be better or how to go about making this a lot cleaner?

This will both be a learning experience of efficient query optimization and general use. :)

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT sCM_CoverageDesc
        FROM SIU_CoverageMap
        WHERE sCM_CoverageDesc = 'ComAutoPhysDam  -  Garagekeepers (Comprehensive)')
BEGIN
    UPDATE SIU_CoverageMap
    SET sCM_CoverageDesc = 'ComAutoPhysDam  -  Garagekeepers (Comprehensive)'
    FROM SIU_CoverageMap
    WHERE sCM_Code = 'GA_GKOTC'
END

IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT sCM_CoverageDesc
        FROM SIU_CoverageMap
        WHERE sCM_CoverageDesc = 'ComAutoPhysDam  -  GarageDealers (Comprehensive) - Autos in Building')
BEGIN
    UPDATE SIU_CoverageMap
    SET sCM_CoverageDesc = 'ComAutoPhysDam  -  GarageDealers (Comprehensive) - Autos in Building'
    FROM SIU_CoverageMap
    WHERE sCM_Code = 'GA_ABLDG'
END

IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT sCM_CoverageDesc
        FROM SIU_CoverageMap
        WHERE sCM_CoverageDesc = 'ComAutoPhysDam  -  GarageDealers Comprehensive - Std Open Lots')
BEGIN
    UPDATE SIU_CoverageMap
    SET sCM_CoverageDesc = 'ComAutoPhysDam  -  GarageDealers Comprehensive - Std Open Lots'
    FROM SIU_CoverageMap
    WHERE sCM_Code = 'GA_LOTS'
END

IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT sCM_CoverageDesc
        FROM SIU_CoverageMap
        WHERE sCM_CoverageDesc = 'ComAutoPhysDam  -  GarageDealers Comprehensive - Non-Std Lots')
BEGIN
    UPDATE SIU_CoverageMap
    SET sCM_CoverageDesc = 'ComAutoPhysDam  -  GarageDealers Comprehensive - Non-Std Lots'
    FROM SIU_CoverageMap
    WHERE sCM_Code = 'GA_NLOTS'
END

IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT sCM_CoverageDesc
        FROM SIU_CoverageMap
        WHERE sCM_CoverageDesc = 'ComAutoPhysDam  -  GarageDealers Comprehensive - Misc Bldg')
BEGIN
    UPDATE SIU_CoverageMap
    SET sCM_CoverageDesc = 'ComAutoPhysDam  -  GarageDealers Comprehensive - Misc Bldg'
    FROM SIU_CoverageMap
    WHERE sCM_Code = 'GA_MISC'
END

IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT sCM_CoverageDesc
        FROM SIU_CoverageMap
        WHERE sCM_CoverageDesc = 'ComAutoPhysDam - Garagekeepers (Collision)')
BEGIN
    UPDATE SIU_CoverageMap
    SET sCM_CoverageDesc = 'ComAutoPhysDam - Garagekeepers (Collision)'
    FROM SIU_CoverageMap
    WHERE sCM_Code = 'GA_GKCOL'
END

IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT sCM_CoverageDesc
        FROM SIU_CoverageMap
        WHERE sCM_CoverageDesc = 'ComAutoPhysDam - Garage Dealers Collision')
BEGIN
    UPDATE SIU_CoverageMap
    SET sCM_CoverageDesc = 'ComAutoPhysDam - Garage Dealers Collision'
    FROM SIU_CoverageMap
    WHERE sCM_Code = 'GA_BLNKC'
END
ELSE
    PRINT ('Table has already been updated.')
```

Comment: Without knowing more about your database or the application, it would be impossible to suggest an optimal... uh, optimization. That being said, whenever I see something of the form `WHERE somefield = 'SOME-REALLY-LONG-STRING'` I'm thinking that optimizing this particular query is going to be the least of your concerns. Can you provide additional insight, perhaps what you are accomplishing with one of the three clauses here?

Comment: Apologies, it's mostly a simple fix of where the "really long string" had two hyphens or lack of further description and now is being cleaned up.

The long description in the IF NOT EXISTS clause is purposefully done to make the update happen. :)

Comment: Do you even need the `IF NOT EXISTS` part then? Would you accomplish the same thing if you unconditionally performed the `UPDATE`s?

Comment: There a few databases that this will be applied to for their tables. Some of them might already have the name corrected, this is just to make sure that only the ones that need the update get fixed.

Comment: But if you perform the `UPDATE` on a database that doesn't need it, no harm done? I'd lose the `IF NOT EXISTS`. You simplify the SQL and halve the number of passes through the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overall reason (business logic) of the IF blocks is not clear.

Why not make a update (patch) table named #Map and do an update regardless of matching.  Below TSQL joins #Map to original table on code to update description.

```
-- Patching table
Create table #Map
(
  Desc1 varchar(128),
  Code1 varchar(16)
);

-- Add data to table
insert into #Map values
('ComAutoPhysDam  -  Garagekeepers (Comprehensive)', 'GA_GKOTC'),
('ComAutoPhysDam  -  GarageDealers (Comprehensive) - Autos in Building', 'GA_ABLDG'),
('ComAutoPhysDam  -  GarageDealers Comprehensive - Std Open Lots', 'GA_LOTS'),
('ComAutoPhysDam  -  GarageDealers Comprehensive - Non-Std Lots', 'GA_NLOTS'),
('ComAutoPhysDam  -  GarageDealers Comprehensive - Misc Bldg', 'GA_MISC'),
('ComAutoPhysDam - Garagekeepers (Collision)', 'GA_GKCOL'),
('ComAutoPhysDam - Garage Dealers Collision', 'GA_BLNKC');

-- Show data in table
select * from #Map;

-- Update regardless
UPDATE SIU_CoverageMap
SET sCM_CoverageDesc = m.Desc1
FROM SIU_CoverageMap c join #Map m on c.sCM_Code = m.Code1
```

Comment: A map table is a good idea, but I'd add `AND c.sCM_CoverageDesc <> m.Desc1` to potentially eliminate some needless I/O.

Comment: That is a beautiful answer and I am going to try this. Thank you :)!

Comment: Good answer and good "add on" by Aaron Bertrand to avoid unnecessary actions.